# findOne - 'Specify the Fields to Return' does not work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

According to the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/), this is how to '**Specify the Fields to Return**':

```
collectionUsers.findOne(
  options,
  // Specify the Fields to Return
  { name: 1, id: 1 } // this does not work

  // Return All but the Excluded Fields
  // { _id: 0 } // this works
)
```

But it does not work as I still get _id in my result, e.g.:

```
{"_id":"59a53ded3a35535198135b17","id":null,"name":"jona"}
```

This is what I expect, e.g.:

```
{"id":null,"name":"jona"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You exclude instead `{ "_id": 0 }`. Don't mix include and exlude either, as it does not work with anything other than `_id`.

Comment: @NeilLunn my issue is not about `exclude`

Comment: Di you even try it? Of course you didn't try because if you did you would have discovered that actually answered what you are asking. It's also [really well documented](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field) and why I'm searching for a reasonable duplicate right now.

Comment: >>  "The _id field is always included unless you explicitly exclude it."